# How to refresh listview in a custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview

I made a custom listview with a custom adapter that populated from database. I can't update my listview whenever the data from database has changed. I have already tried using notifysetdatachanged() but it didn't work. Maybe it's because I putted the code in a wrong way. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

**ContactActivity.java**

```js
    public  void getImages2(){
        class GetImages2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                super.onPostExecute(v);
                loading.dismiss();
                customList = new CustomList(ContactActivity.this,GetAlImages2.imageURLs,GetAlImages2.bitmaps,GetAlImages2.code,GetAlImages2.name,GetAlImages2.phone,GetAlImages2.email);
                listView.setAdapter(customList);
                customList.notifyDataSetChanged();
  
                }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    getAlImages2.getAllImages2();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
        GetImages2 getImages = new GetImages2();
        getImages.execute();
    }
```

**CustomList.java**

```js
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Bitmap[] bitmaps;
    private String[] urls;
    private String[] code;
    private String[] name;
    private String[] email;
    private String[] phone;

    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context,  String[] urls, Bitmap[] bitmaps, String[] code, String[] name, String[] phone, String[] email) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_contact_item, urls);
        this.context = context;
        this.urls= urls;
        this.bitmaps= bitmaps;
        this.code= code;
        this.name= name;
        this.phone= phone;
        this.email =  email;
    }

}
```

**[EDIT]**

Finally I have found the solution of my problem. My listview should have checked first whether the listview's adapter is empty or not. I added this code to my onPostExecute. Thanks for all your help.

```js
customList = new CustomList(ContactActivity.this,GetAlImages2.imageURLs,GetAlImages2.bitmaps,GetAlImages2.code,GetAlImages2.name,GetAlImages2.phone,GetAlImages2.email);
if(listView.getAdapter() == null){ //Adapter not set yet.
   listView.setAdapter(customList);
}
else{ //Already has an adapter
   listView.setAdapter(customList);
   customList.notifyDataSetChanged();
   listView.invalidateViews();
   listView.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

Comment: the data is setting to the listview or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

Inside your `onResume()` add this

```
if (listvew!= null) {
  listvew.invalidateViews();
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I've tried your code, and then I got an error like this.  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.irmaelita.bpsgosurvey/com.irmaelita.bpsgosurvey.ContactActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.irmaelita.bpsgosurvey.CustomList.notifyDataSetChanged()'. What should I do now?

Comment: if my answer  usefull to others please upvote my answer@IrmaElita

Answer (score 1):

please try these

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code here will run in UI thread
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

OR

```
someActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
});
```

Comment: I putted your first code in my onPostExecute, but it didn't work. It didn't update the listview. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement loader callback to the activity that contains the listview .. and you can follow this answer
[Listview not updating after database update and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656325/listview-not-updating-after-database-update-and-adapter-notifydatasetchanged)

The more common way to code this is:

Add this interface to your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implementsLoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

In `onCreate`, set up the adapter (note that the cursor is null at this point):

```
String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, TodoTable.COLUMN_ID};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.todo_row, null, from, to, 0);  //Note that the cursor is null
lw.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Initiate the loader:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

This calls `onCreateLoader` in a background thread (so if your query is long running it won't block the UI thread). When it finishes, `onLoadFinished` is called on the UI thread where you can swap in the new cursor.

After you do a delete or update, restart the loader:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```

This calls `onLoaderReset` which removes the existing cursor from the adapter and then calls `onCreateLoader` again to swap in a new one.

Finally add these methods:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)
{
    String[] from = new String[] { TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, TodoTable.COLUMN_ID};
    String where = TodoTable.COLUMN_DELETED + " = ?";

    Loader<Cursor> loader = new CursorLoader(this, TodoContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, from, where, new String[] {"0"}, null);     
    return loader;
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
{
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
{
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: I'm newbie. And I don't know how to implement that code to my code. Could you please show me how to do it?